# Tree recursion going infinitely

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, tree

I have made a code to construct a binary tree from a vector. The problem is that when I call `inOrder(root)` it's going in the infinite recursion i.e. root never becomes `nullptr`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    explicit Node(int element) {
        data = element;
        left = nullptr;
        right= nullptr;
    }
};

Node* construct_tree(Node* root, vector<int> &vec, int i) {
    if(i < vec.size()) {
        Node* new_node = new Node(vec[i]);
        root = new_node;
        root->left = construct_tree(root, vec, 2*i + 1);
        root->right = construct_tree(root, vec, 2*i + 2);
    }
    return root;
}

void inOrder(Node* root) {
    if (root != nullptr) {
        inOrder(root->left);
        int n = root->data;
        cout << n << " ";
        inOrder(root->right);
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    Node *root = nullptr;
    root = construct_tree(root, vec, 0);
    cout << root->data << " ";
    cout << root->left->data;
    inOrder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Possible fix?

Comment: As @MikeCAT shows in the solution, the error is in the `construct_tree` routine. You made an error when designing the function. It recursively builds a tree and explicitly assigns subtrees to a `left` and `right` members of the current node. As a result it should return the root of a tree built, which is a `new_node` (possibly `nullptr`, if `i` is too large), but not a `root` passed by a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `root` from `construct_tree`, so it may assign `root` to `root->left` or `root->right`, creating circle, when the condition `i < vec.size()` is false.

In this case, you won't need the argument `root` because its value is never used in the function `construct_tree`.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    explicit Node(int element) {
        data = element;
        left = nullptr;
        right= nullptr;
    }
};

Node* construct_tree( vector<int> &vec, int i) {
    if(i < vec.size()) {
        Node* new_node = new Node(vec[i]);
        // stop using root and use new_node directly
        new_node->left = construct_tree(vec, 2*i + 1);
        new_node->right = construct_tree(vec, 2*i + 2);
        return new_node;
    } else {
        // return nullptr when the condition is false
        return nullptr;
    }
}

void inOrder(Node* root) {
    if (root != nullptr) {
        inOrder(root->left);
        int n = root->data;
        cout << n << " ";
        inOrder(root->right);
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    Node *root = nullptr;
    root = construct_tree(vec, 0); // remove the argument root
    cout << root->data << " ";
    cout << root->left->data;
    inOrder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Node* insertLevelOrder(int arr[], Node* root, int i, int n)
{
    if (i < n)
    {
        Node* temp = newNode(arr[i]);
        root = temp;
        root->left = insertLevelOrder(arr,root->left, 2 * i + 1, n);
        root->right = insertLevelOrder(arr,root->right, 2 * i + 2, n);
    }
    return root;
}`
How does this function work with arrays then but not with vector?